# How do they create that kind of "twisting zoom"?

Tags: video, video-editor, camera

I'm new to video production and editing. I'm wondering how I should use my camera (maybe with some other tools) to create a kind of twisting zoom, where the camera moves towards the front of the subject at the same time to the subject moves, without shaking the camera. I'd like to do something similar to what is in the video below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an editing technique and it is not a zoom. There is no change in focal length. The subject is on a product or photography [turntable](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Product-Turntables/ci/18679/N/3861984724). You can even [make your own](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=diy+photography+turntable). The camera is kept fixed on a tripod with no zooming. Just position the camera and the subject to capture the motion you want and rotate the turntable.